# SSZipArchive not working with In-App

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, unzip

I create a list to download product by In-App Purchase hosted by apple, but when buy and download the package content the SSZipArchive not working, this is my code:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] startDownloads:transaction.downloads];

                [self completeTransaction:transaction];

                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'am trying to unzip my package

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads {

    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    for (SKDownload *download in downloads)
    {

        switch (download.downloadState) {

            case SKDownloadStateActive:
                NSLog(@"Download progress %f", download.progress);
                NSLog(@"Download time  %f", download.timeRemaining);
                break;

            case SKDownloadStateFinished:

                NSLog(@"Finished!!");
                NSLog(@"Content URL  %@", download.contentURL);

                [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",download.contentURL] toDestination:docsDir];

                break;

            case SKDownloadStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Failed");
                break;
            case SKDownloadStateCancelled:

                NSLog (@"Cancelled");
                break;
            case SKDownloadStatePaused:
            case SKDownloadStateWaiting:
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

where am I doing wrong?

THX solved using this tutorial: [tutorial here](http://xinsight.ca/blog/iap-content-download-in-ios6/)

Comment: "Not working" doesn't really tell us much.  What is happening?

Comment: Purchase working well and download content in to a Caches folder in ZIP format, but SSZipArchive have difficult to pick the and unzip file in to a Documents directory

Comment: The `SSZipArchive` appears to have a method that accepts an `NSError` object, so use that version and start reporting the errors.